# New ID signature for Ebon Hawk: does my choice matter?

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

On Nar Shaddaa it's required to change the ID for Ebon Hawk. You can check multiple optional terminals to unlock additional IDs. Final choice looked like this for me:

[image]

But does it matter which one you use? Is there any consequences? I think you end up in the next location anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently playing through KOTOR 2 on my phone, thanks to the Aspyr team. I actually just passed this part of the game, though I was only given the options of the Silver Zephyr, and the signature from B-5D8. I made a quick save to try both, and there was no difference. The cutscene of GOTO's ship capturing yours plays out regardless, and I would assume that if I could have chosen Toorna's Profits or Alakandor's, the same cutscene would have played.

It seems silly to go through all the trouble of getting the codes, just to be able to use any of the three from the docks. But I wonder if there's a possibility that the player could somehow not have the docked ships' signatures, whether that's just not investigating the terminals at the docks, having too low a Computer skill, etc.